# conditionally disable an option using react select not work when change option props passed to the Select

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-select

I'm trying to conditionally make an option of a select disabled, for example, if two items are selected, the the third option is diabled, if one or three items are selected, the third option is enabled. However the Select option does not change when selected number of items change even it's passed as props of the option. When I console.log, I do see the option object disabled value changed when I change selected items numbers. May I know why the Select does not re render? Thanks!

```
class parentComponent extends PureComponent{
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  this.state = {
    options:[]
  }
}
render() {
 const {
  countOfItems
 } = this.props
 
 let options = [...somefunction()];
 if (somecondition1) {
  options.options.filter(...)
 }
 if (somecondition2) {
  options.options.filter(...)
 }
 
 this.setState({options})
 ......
 if (countOfItems === 2) {
 options[3].disabled = true
 } else {
 options[3].disabled = false
 }
console.log(options[3])
......
return (
 <Select
  options ={options}
  isOptionDisabled = {(option) => option.disabled}
  ......


)
}
}
```

Comment: brother you are doing it wrong. logic is right but it disabling will not be rendered until you setstate and cause the component to re-render updated dom and what is options . Is it state or a variable?

Comment: Hi @WasifAli , thanks! The options is a variable in this component. May I know why it does not re render? The "options" object is changed and it's passed as prop to the Select as options ={options}, so the prop of Select changed, why the Select is not rerender?

Comment: React component render their UI/DOM after DOM diffing which causes the component to make a new reference of return statement and render updated changes to UI. which is triggered by  useSTATE hook. If you are not updating state. No dom diffing occur. So you'll have the old reference of Dom.

Comment: So to make the new changes reflect in your UI. You have to play with state. Make your options variable state. i.e const [options , setOptions] = usestate({}). Then set it accordingly. I'll be working fine

Comment: Thank you @WasifAli ! It's an class component, so I should add this option to state and setState to change it?  The options variable is defined in render() like: let options = [...somefunction(arg1,arg2...)] and then there are some filters function, should I just make the option in the state as an empty array, then change all these functions to setState? And also, even if the props passed to the child component changes, if the parent component's state is not changeing, it's not going to re render?

Comment: never ever  setstate in render lifecycle.
Please share code on codesandbox. I can fix it for you.

Comment: Hi @WasifAli Thank you so much! The original code is so long and has some connections with other components which I'm not sure whether it has something to do with the issue so it's hard to put it on sandbox. But I just find that this works: I make another boolean state: isDisableSecondOption:false, then if numerofCound === 2, setState({isDisableSecondOption:true}),otherwise set it false, and when I use the Select, I do a map in the options like: <Select options={options.map(option,index) => {if (index === 2 {return ...option, isDisabled:isDisableSecondOption:true} return option)}},

Comment: So I disabled or enabled this second option of the Select based on the isDisableSecondOption in the state and pass this in this option, and it works! Not sure is this an appropriate way to do this? Since the options variable is changed by some function inside the render() and hard to make it the same in the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React component render their UI/DOM after DOM diffing which causes the component to make a new reference of return statement and render updated changes to UI. which is triggered by useSTATE hook. If you are not updating state. No dom diffing occur. So you'll have the old reference of Dom.

**You can do it this way**

class Options {

```
this.state={options:[]}


componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.countOfItems !== prevProps.countOfItems) {
let tempOptions = [...this.state.options]
if (this.props.countOfItems === 2) {
 tempOptions[3].disabled = true
 } else {
 tempOptions[3].disabled = false
 }
this.setState({options:tempOptions})
  }
}





render() {
   
    ......
    return (
     <Select
      options ={this.state.options}
      isOptionDisabled = {(option) => option.disabled}
      ......
    
    
    )
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wasif! I try to use the setState, but I got "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate" May I know what could be the reason? in the original file, in the render() { let options = [...somefunction()]; if(somecondition1){options=options.filter(...)}  if(someconditions2) {options=options.filter(...)}  this.setState({options})} So basically I add this setState after all the original filter adjustment of variable options, may I know why I got this maximum update error? Thank you!

Comment: did you put this.setstate in condition ? I've edited answer.
If it works then kindly mark it as accepted and let me know.

Comment: @xixi maximum calldepth errors occurs because your setstate is not wrapped in condition.   it should be  if (this.props.countOfItems !== prevProps.countOfItems) {
......
this.setState({options:tempOptions})
  }

Comment: Thank you Wasif! Just make it as accepted! So the component itself has those define and filter function for the options variable, I try to make the state.options the same as the options variable , but got that error, those filters are for the options variable not conditionally render

Comment: error? can you show me?

Comment: It's the "maximum calldepth errors" after I added the setState, I try to make the options in the state the same as the variable before doing the update. I modified the code in the question